# I try to create a GUI in python to read a file and write a new file but the syntax error shows up

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x

In this program, I try to read a g.code file to generate a new text file.
Firstly, I browse a gcode file from where I want. I, then, browse a folder I want to save. Finally, I run and write some codes and save them as a text file.
I have a problem with function run. When I click run, the SyntaxError shows up.

However, this is only some part of my codes.

```
from tkinter import *
import os
global file_path
global folder_path
import math

i = 0
fenster = Tk()
fenster.title("Gcode Reader")
fenster.geometry("600x400")

def open_file():
    file_path = ''
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    file_path = filename
entry.delete(0, END)
entry.insert(0, file_path)
filename.close()

mf = Frame(fenster)
mf.pack()

f1 = Frame(mf, width=100, height=50)
f1.pack(fill=X)


file_path = StringVar

Label(f1,text="Select Your File").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='e')
entry = Entry(f1, width=50, textvariable=file_path)
entry.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=2,pady=2,sticky='we',columnspan=25)
Button(f1, text="Browse", command=open_file).grid(row=0, column=27, sticky='ew', padx=8, pady=4)

def run():
 out_file = open(os.path.join(folder_path, entry2.get()+".txt")
 with open(file_path) as in_file :
  for line in file_path :
    if 'G1 X' in line[0:10] and i==0 :
    i=i+1
    a=line.find('Y',0,13)
    b=line.find('X',0,10)
    c=a-1
    d=line.find(' ',a,a+10)
    x1=float(line[b+1:c])
    y1=float(line[a+1:d])


mainloop()
```

Comment: Would you be so kind to add the error message you get?

Comment: @jotrocken Thank you for your response.
The cursor moves to "with" and the message is "invalid syntax"

Answer (score 1):

Could it be a typo? You're missing a bracket in this line:

```
def run():
    out_file = open(os.path.join(folder_path, entry2.get()+".txt")
                                                                  ^
```

That's why you're getting the mentioned error:

```
with open(file_path) as in_file:
   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Just change the line to:

```
    out_file = open(os.path.join(folder_path, entry2.get()+".txt"))
```

Comment: Oh yes! Thank you a lot.

Comment: No problem. Consider making it the accepted answer if it helped.